# In Redux, there is one connect for each container?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my previous projects, I usually have only one `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)`. But when I check the official [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world/src/containers) today, I find there is almost one `connect()` for each container.

what are the benefits to have multiple `connect()`?

Comment: connect function just allow component to get access to data located in store. It is kinda controller between store(model) and component(view) that needs some data from store. This function is capable to "plug into" store as many component as you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine a Redux version of Stack Overflow's Q&A page. You'd have quite a few components: the question and its votes, answers and their votes, the Markdown editor for additional answers, the profile link at the top, and related and network questions on the right.  The corresponding Redux store could have sub-objects for the active question, active answers, related questions, user profile, and Markdown editor.

You could use a single top-level `connect`, as you mentioned, but `connect`ing each component individually offers *performance* and *encapsulation*:

- A single top-level `connect` means that the top-level `App` gets re-rendered whenever any Redux store value changes, then it has to pass down those props to each of its child components (which either have to re-render or check `shouldComponentUpdate`).  If you `connect` each component separately, then, e.g., when you type something in the Markdown editor and update the editor's slice of the store, only the Markdown editor re-renders.
- A single top-level `connect` means that the top-level `App` needs to know everything under it, so that it can pass down all of the needed props and events itself.  Individual `connect`s offer encapsulation: the profile bar can `connect` to the props and action creators that it needs, and higher-level components don't have to know or care about the details.