# Passing properties to components vs accessing via redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's say in `ParentComponent` I use redux to set an application state variable in the store like `isGood: true`.  Now I can pass this to the child props by rendering `<ChildComponent isGood={this.props.isGood} />` but I could also connect `ChildComponent` to the store itself and grab `isGood` from the application state.  Is one of these preferred over another and why?

*edit:* I think I should mention that I am asking because while passing props down seems the most "react"-way of doing things (to me anyway), I am finding that I like the readability of connecting child components to the store-there is a list of what I have available and with destructuring (how I like to write my mapStateToProps) I can see right away where the values come from.  That said, I didn't want to start adopting that as a standard if there is some sort of performance/anti-pattern/etc issue with doing so.

Comment: This answer provides one point of view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297383/in-redux-there-is-one-connect-for-each-container

Answer (score 2):

The initial redux documentation suggested using a top-down approach with one parent container, but this has since changed. Dan Abramov provides some good insight [here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/668585589609005056).

Comment: Insightful tweets.  Thanks!